# Laravel checkbox input old not working properly

Tags: php, laravel, checkbox

I have a form. After submission of the form if it has some error then it redirects to the same page and pre-populate the data that user submitted. I have `3 checkbox` fields in that form. Suppose user has checked only the `first checkbox` and submitted the form. So if the form has some error it will redirect to the same page, but the problem is when it redirects here again then `all the checkboxes got selected instead of only the 1st one`.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Hobbies: <span><em>{{$errors->first('hobbies')}}</em></span></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="Cricket" @if (is_array(old('hobbies'))) && (in_array('Cricket', old('hobbies'))) checked @endif> Cricket
    <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="Football" @if (is_array(old('hobbies'))) && (in_array('Football', old('hobbies'))) checked @endif> Football
    <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="Badminton" @if (is_array(old('hobbies'))) && (in_array('Badminton', old('hobbies'))) checked @endif> Badminton
</div>
```

Comment: have you checked with Input::old( ?

Comment: no. I have not checked it

Comment: which version of laravel you are using?

Comment: i am using laravel 5.4

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="Cricket" {{ !empty(old('hobbies')) && (in_array('Cricket', old('hobbies'))) ? 'checked' : '' }}> Cricket change all three lines like this

Comment: okay let me try it

Comment: Hey it works. Thanks buddy. You can post this as a answer so that I can mark it as accept

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153433/discussion-between-rahul-meshram-and-shan-biswas).

Comment: There are many ways to skin a cat. Don't you want to know **why** your code doesn't work, instead of just trying another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this way to make it work,

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Hobbies: <span><em>{{$errors->first('hobbies')}}</em></span></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="Cricket" {{ !empty(old('hobbies')) && (in_array('Cricket', old('hobbies'))) ? 'checked' : '' }}> Cricket
    <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="Cricket" {{ !empty(old('hobbies')) && (in_array('Football', old('hobbies'))) ? 'checked' : '' }}> Football
    <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="Cricket" {{ !empty(old('hobbies')) && (in_array('Badminton', old('hobbies'))) ? 'checked' : '' }}> Badminton
</div>
```

Give it a try, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You have unbalanced and misplaced parentheses, so your `if` is not evaluation correctly.

```
@if (is_array(old('hobbies')) && in_array('Badminton', old('hobbies')))
```